# Creating mosaicplot with different colors in each field

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmosaic

I want to create a mosicplot (2x2), where the counterpart have the same color.

So the mosaicplot should have a colorpalette like:

[image]

Here is the structure of the data i used for the graphic:

```
data <- data.frame(G1 = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   G2 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A","A", "B", "B", "B"))
```

I already tried to solve this with defining a third variable, which is then defining the colors:

```
data$C1 <- ifelse((data$G1 == "A" & data$G2 == "A") | (data$G1 == "B" & data$G2 == "B") ,
                    data$C1 <- "1", data$C1 <- "0")
ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(G1, G2), fill = C1))
```

Unfortunately this results in:

[image]

Maybe someone knows a solution, whereby these little stripes are not visible (for example the blue line in field G1 == B and C1:G2 = 1:A)?

Thanks

Comment: What stripes are you referring to? If you mean the plot background, add  `theme_void()` to your ggplot2 code.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?

Comment: @Phil, for example, it would be great, when the blue line in the field G1 = B and C1:G2 = 1:A disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this, & the reason is that ggmosaic's `prodcalc` function calculates the position for every combination of `c(G1, G2, C1)` in your example, even the ones with count = 0. These zero-width rectangles lead to 2 issues:

1. They show up as super-thin lines on the mosaic plot, which you have already observed;
2. They are also taken into account when offset is applied, so even if we hide the them, alignment for the remaining rectangles in the mosaic plot will go out of sync.

The second issue can be amplified with a higher value for offset (default is 0.01):

```
p <- ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(G1, G2), fill = C1),
              offset = 0.1)
p
```

[image: plot with high offset]

Adjusting the transparency of these zero-width rectangles will address issue 1 but not issue 2:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(G1, G2), fill = C1,
                  alpha = ifelse(after_stat(xmin) == after_stat(xmax), 0, 1)),
              offset = 0.1) +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image: plot with high offset + transparency tweak]

I don't have a perfect solution for this, but if you are willing to tolerate lack of space between the rectangles, setting `offset = 0` and applying a white outline over everything (to replace the offset's function in distinguishing each rectangle from the rest) can mitigate the appearance:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(G1, G2), fill = C1),
              offset = 0, colour = "white")
```

[image: plot from workaround with zero offset]